# Timeout for getting data from SQL Server on webpag but Crystal Report is fine in VS2015

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a complex stored procedure which executes a few stored procedures in SQL Server. On my webpage I have a function to get the data into dataset, but it has timeout issue. However it has no problem on Crystal Report. Would someone tell me how I can solve this problem?

Thank in advance

Comment: Think we need some more information.  How are you connecting to your SQL server?  How are you preforming your commands?

Comment: @Hursey I used the connection string in my code for example:<add key="connectionStringToSQL" value="server=SQL\test;database=OrderTest;uid=tester;PWD=xxxx"/>  and sqldataadapter

Comment: First thing I would do is test the database connection in a way that removes Crystal Reports from the equation.  Try loading a datatable with a result set and see if you can display or print the data.